# sql | need query to filter data

Tags: sql, group-by

I have this dataset where i need to figure out, 
For which account there is both a -ve and a +ve amount for a given date through out the month.

also to display these accounts with respective amount and date

```
Date  acct   amt 
x      123   -1.1
x      123    2.3
y      234    1.4
y      234    1.5
y      234   -4.3
z      345    8.2
z      345    1.3
```

your help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
Select date, acct, amt 
from table_name 
where date between 'x' and 'z' 
order by date, acct;
```

now i can see the data like i have shown above but i am not able to figure out what to use to move forward.

expected result (account with z date is gone as it had both +ve transactions):

```
Date  acct   amt 
x      123   -1.1
x      123    2.3
y      234    1.4
y      234    1.5
y      234   -4.3
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: What SQL have you written to try to do this?

Comment: Select date, acct, amt from table_name where date between 'x' and 'z' order by date, acct;  now i can see the data like i have shown above but i am not able to figure out what to use to move forward. i am beginner here. if anyone could just point me out in right direction, i will appreciate that.

Comment: can be more than 2 values for date?

Comment: yes, i have accts with multiple transactions on a single date.

Comment: can you update your data with that sample?

Comment: any negative and any positve value? For a moment I tought should have the same value... `value = -value`. So all three acct have a negative and a positive value?

Answer (score 0):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/26630/2)**

You decide what you want to do with `0`

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
JOIN 
    (
    SELECT "Date", "acct"
    FROM Table1 
    GROUP BY "Date", "acct"
    HAVING 
        MIN("amt") < 0
    AND MAX("amt") > 0
    ) T
  ON Table1."Date" = T."Date"
 AND Table1."acct" = T."acct"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Date | acct |  amt |
|------|------|------|
|    x |  123 | -1.1 |
|    x |  123 |  2.3 |
|    y |  234 |  1.4 |
|    y |  234 |  1.5 |
|    y |  234 | -4.3 |
```

Comment: Thank You so so much Juan but this is what i managed to do with the help other sources:  select * from
(Select date, acct, amt, 
case when amt<0 then amt else 0 end as amt_nve, 
case when amt>0 then amt else 0 end as amt_pve
from Table_name
)
where amt_nve<0 and amt_pve>0
;

Comment: I am going to try and understand your method now, again thanks much.

Comment: the inner `select` find what are the `date, acct` with a negative and a positve values. Then you join with your original table to get all rows with same `date, acct` as the list you have.